# "Change Item Order" in a filtered list still show everything in the list

Tags: list-view, ordering

Using Sharepoint 2010, I created a custom link list.  This custom link list has a column for status (In Progress, Not Started, On Hold, Done).

I have a couple of views:
* "In Progress" view - all the items that status != Done.  This view is enabled with "Allow users to change item orders in this view"
* "Done" view - all the items that have status = Done.

In the "In Progress" view, "Change Item Order" allows us to change the priority of in-progress items.  When I use the "Change Item Order" button, it displays all the items even though the view displays filtered item.

How do I change "Change Item Order" so that it would only allow me to change the order of the items from the filtered results?

Answer (score 1):

Its a ribbon button that executes `/_layouts/reorder.aspx?List=[GUID]` in the modal dialog window. So I see these options:

1. try to find out what other query parameters `reorder.aspx` could have
2. quick look into it, reaveals that it relies on `m_listItems` javascript variable, you may try to redefine it.
3. edit `reorder.aspx` code
4. create new ribbon button that will call customReorder.aspx with your functionality